# Java nested package visibility

Tags: java, package

Often when I'm designing some new component of the project I'm having a limitation that I can't right away work out...

Imagine a package "component" and in this component package you have some public classes/interfaces which are naturally designed to be shared publicly and some classes/interfaces (ComponentSpecificStuff) that are needed in inner packages but those should not be visible from outside of package...

Now with current java possibilities the only way I achieve this is by violating the (not expose Stuff outside "component" package) moment...

How do you workaround this?

Comment: There's no such concept as an "inner package" in Java. Packages are not hierarchical as far as the compiler is concerned - the "hierarchy" is just human pattern matching for organization, effectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do it till some extent by using internal keyword in package name.
Example you have a package

```
com.myPackage.component
```

you can have another package as

```
com.myPackage.component.internal.blahblah
```

When you use the keyword internal it is not exposed to other jars and not available for usage outside the jar but can be used inside the jar by another package. Here the internal package is extending `com.myPackage.component` further down the hierarchy. As quote by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) `Packages are not hierarchical as far as the compiler is concerned - the "hierarchy" is just human pattern matching for organization, effectively.` That is what I mean by extending the package further.

---

## EDIT

You can define a class package private by not giving any access modifier to the class 
Example :

```
class PackagePrivateClass{

}
```

You can import this class in the same package but outside the package it doesn't allow you to use it.

Comment: Thank you, altough i didnt know about special meaning of internal package but this is partial answer for the problem... in some situations its not reasonable to devide project just to make internall stuff not visible... So i guess what i've described is not yet possible with current java as we have it?

Comment: I've heared java 9 jigsaw is about to do something about that.

Comment: I know about package protected visibility. The whole problem is that it wont allow not only outside but inside too, but i've got your point, its not a hierarchy... too bad its not :(

Comment: When you put public classes in these internal packages, they will still be accessible by classes that include this jar on the classpath.

Comment: @Dormouse I don't think so cause the the internal keyword in package naming the class loader doesn't export those classes in that package when you create a Jar. You can use it in the same jar You wont be able to use it where the jar is imported.

Comment: I've tried this with maven-built jars (no manifest) and everything compiled and ran. On Oracle's Java 8 JVM btw. While I do think the internal packages are a good way of telling your API's clients not to touch these classes, there seems to be no magic preventing them from doing so.

Comment: I have had this on code on java6 and java7 and didn't see the results that you are seeing. I read about it that it still exists may be you are doing something wrong can you create http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post a new question and send me the link. I can take a look @ it.