# How to organise a library in packages without exposing internal classes

Tags: java

I'm developing a Java library. To organise things internally, I put my classes in 2 packages: A and B. I only want to expose some classes from package A to the library user. But internally, I need to access to some of the classes in package B from package A.

How can do this, without exposing the classes in package B to the library user? If I make them package-private, I can't access them myself from A. If I make them public, they're visible to the library user.

Do I have to put all the code in my library in one big package, so I can access internal package-private classes?

Comment: You cannot. Not until [Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/). Maybe. Anything `public` is globally `public`.

Comment: Why are the classes in Package B if you are only accessing them from Package A? Your design seems conceptually flawed.

Comment: I'm mostly accessing classes within the same package, but sometimes I need access to a class in the other package. For example, a package that contains graphics classes will also sometimes need access to a class in the package that contains file management.

Comment: @Bartez But why? That sounds like a flawed design. Graphics package should *not* be accessing internal details of File Management package. Don't cross concerns. Your File Management package should expose a clear cut interface on how it should be used. It should only be used via that interface if used by clients. If graphics needs to use file management for some reason, it is acting as a client of file management.

Comment: I did find this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302066/java-nested-package-visibility
Does including "internal" in your package name automatically hide the package? Or is this just an Eclipse autocomplete convention?

Comment: @VinceEmigh In the example I gave, let's say I don't want my library to expose file access functionality, but I do need quite a few classes that handle file access internally. So I want to put them in a separate package to organise my internal organization, without exposing them externally.

I'm thinking it's best for the user of my library if I just put everything in 1 big package, so I can make the File classes package-private, but that seems so ugly for me.
I also have a Sound package whose classes I want to expose. Some Sound classes internally also need the same FileManagement package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is done with different jars. The one jar will have your A package with classes that end user needs to use. The other jars will contain classes that your A classes will have dependency on. 
This is usually done with tools like Maven. As a good example is the use of Apache commons libraries. You can have them imported in your class but dont need to include them in your jar. You can simply have Maven require them during runtime.